# How to check that frame does not contain jlabel with specific text with help of Assertj?

Tags: java, assertj

I want to test my simple application with AssertJ.
I can check that text is showing like that:

```
frame.label(JLabelMatcher.withText(text).andShowing());
```

But is there any way to check that specific text not showing?

Answer (score 0):

As a result, I solved this issue in such a not pretty way:

```
public void iDontSeeText(String text) {
    try {
        frame.label(JLabelMatcher.withText(Pattern.compile(".*" + text + ".*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)).andShowing());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Control isn't found. Test complete successful
        return;
    }
    // Control is found. Execute exception
    throw new RuntimeException("Text \"" + text + "\" is found in frame.");
}
```